# Effective class instanciation in software

Tags: python, class, logging, instantiation

I have written a `coloured_output` module which holds a class named `ColouredMsg`.
To use it I only have to create an instance of `ColouredMsg`:

```
from coloured_output import ColouredMsg
cm = ColouredMsg()
```

then use it this way:

```
warning_msg = cm.warn(*parameters)
error_msg = cm.error(*parameters)
```

The thing is I am planning to use this class for console logs, in a software:

```
cm = ColouredMsg()
print cm.warn(*parameters)
```

As one might guess, this call will be often made, in almost every module. So at this point, I'd like to know which practice is best. Either I stick with this way, and I will have to import the module `coloured_output` and to declare an instance of `ColouredMsg` at the beginning of each module, or I can make a general function in the `coloured_output` module, like this:

```
def warn(*parameters):
    cm = ColouredMsg()
    return cm.warn(*parameters)
```

then in my software:

```
import coloured_output as co
# ...
co.warn(*parameters)
```

But here I would have to create an instance of `ColouredMsg` everytime I want to print a coloured message, which would be heavy and should probably be avoided.

Which leaves me with a third choice, I could create a general instance of `ColouredMsg` in my `coloured_output` module, which would look like:

```
class ColouredMsg():

    def warn(*parameters):
        message = do_whatever_is_needed(*parameters)
        return message

cm = ColouredMsg()

def warn(*parameters):
    return cm.warn(*parameters)
```

So I have two choices: either declaring a general instance in each of my software modules, or declaring a general instance in the `coloured_output` module. Or something else I have not thought about.

I would embrace any suggestion.

Comment: Seems like this should be a logging [Formatter object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects), then you can configure the loggers to do the work for you.

Comment: Nice suggestion I will probably use it at some point.

Comment: I see you already accepted an answer but I really think that reinventing the wheel here is wrong

why not use something like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorlog/2.0.0?

Comment: @yoav glazner: Isn't reinventing the wheel a nice thing to do for learning and practicing purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel's suggestion in the comments is good.

But if you *really* want to do this yourself, I recommend using a hidden instance in the module, rather than creating a new temporary instance in each function call. The "hidden instance" approach is used in the standard library, eg, that's what the `random` module does for the standard random functions.

Comment: Nice to know this "hidden instance" practice is common.

Comment: @kaligne: In general (but not always), imitating the practices of the Python standard library, is a Good Thing. :) I'm sure there are various other examples of modules that use hidden instances, but I can't think of any off-hand... maybe `time` or `datetime`.